# how can i use if - else statement in jquery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am developing one project in asp.net c# . Here are two buttons in jquery yes or no . If I clicked the yes button then the "no" button will be hide and vice versa . Anyone please help me . ......

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if("#btnYes").click(function () {
        $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('1');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnNo").click(function () {
        $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('0');
    });
});
</script>
```

- And here #hdnYesNoAnswer is hidden value for taking the yes or no value from that jquery .

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library

Comment: What the use of if in `if("#btnYes")`? You have a typo just remove `if` from line

Comment: You need to look at what you're doing and think about what it means, I realise at first that can be hard since everything is new. Formatting nicely can help make things clearer. First off you can put all that javascript in one `<script>` tag. Secondly `$(document).ready(function () {})` means whatever code is inside this will be hit once the page is ready, so even if `if("#btnYes").click` was valid it would be checking this once the page is ready which surely isn't what you intend.

Comment: Also, think about the logic you want here. "If I clicked the yes button then the "no" button will be hide and vice versa". So then if you click yes and the no button hides, the user can no longer change their decision. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's click handlers respond to click events. So you don't need to query `if` something was clicked; you just define what should happen when it *is* clicked, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // when a button is clicked, hide it and show the other button
  $("#btnYes, #btnNo").click(function () {
    $("#btnYes, #btnNo").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  // when yes is clicked, set the answer to 1
  $("#btnYes").click(function () {
    $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('1');
  });

  // when no is clicked, set the answer to 0
  $("#btnNo").click(function () {
    $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('0');
  });
});
```

Comment: They asked for hiding the other button too.

Answer (score 3):

You could even don't use if else.

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnYes,#btnNo").click(function () {
    // +true is 1, +false is 0
    $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val(+(this.id == 'btnYes'));
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the slickest answer but it may be a bit difficult to understand for presumably a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnYes").click(function () {
        $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('1');
    });

    $("#btnNo").click(function () {
        $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('0');
    });
});
```